# how to pass data objects between the routes in angular 2 Final version

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm migrating my application from Angular2 Rc3 to Angular (2.0.0) Final Version.I have code in Rc3 like this

```
constructor(public router:Router, public routeData: RouteData){
   this.routeData.data = { idNum: this.idNumber, message: myMessage };
   this.router.navigate(['ActivityList']);

}
```

In the current version RouteData was deprecated and replaced by ActivatedRoute.Could anyone please help me how to pass these objects through the ActivatedRoute.

Comment: Is this idNum and message visible in your url or not?

Comment: No, they are not visible.If we use routeParams then it will show in the url but the problem with the Params is it accepts only strings not objects.

Comment: One thing you could do is use a resolver. Resolvers are described quite extensively here: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html. This is not passing the data directly but you could store it somewhere and fetch it from the resolve. Haven't found a way to directly pass it as described above in RC3

Answer (score 2):

You can try JSON.stringify(your_object):

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {Router, NavigationExtras} from "@angular/router";
@Component({..})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(router:Router) {
       this.router = router;
    }

  let navextras: NavigationExtras={            
           queryParams:{"message":JSON.stringify({"id": "1", "text":"yourmessages"})}
         };
  sendStringParam() {

        this.router.navigate([ 'Message'], navextras);
        return false; 
  }
}
```

From your component receiving data:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
@Component({.....})
export class ReceiverComponent {
    public message:any;
    constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
        this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.message = params["message"];
        console.log(this.message.id);
        console.log(this.message.text);
         });

    }

}
```

Comment: In `ReceiverComponent` you should use `JSON.parse(this.message)`, not?